# Merging multiple MrSid files in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, merge, mosaic, mrsid

I've got multiple sid files that make up my county of interest.

I need to get all the sid files into one and STILL have the sid file type after merging.

Anyone know how to do this in ArcMap 10.2.2?

Answer (score 2):

You can't in ArcGIS. The MrSID format is [read only](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm#GUID-202A062A-5111-46B8-AEFC-B1B7CAC60FBD). If you want to output to sid, you need to purchase the [LizardTech](http://www.lizardtech.com/) MrSID encoder, or find some other software that incorporates this proprietary encoder (I think you can write to sid with GDAL if you compile the MrSID driver against a purchased LizardTech encoding SDK).